# Moments of physical qualities other than density

Tags: temperature, integration, density

If I have some genuine physical object $\Omega$ (that I can describe mathematically) and want to find its center of mass, I can compute its moments to get each coordinate of that center; for example, the $x$-coordinate would be

$$\displaystyle \dfrac{\iiint_{\Omega} x\delta(x,y,z)~dV}{\iiint_{\Omega}}.$$

where $\delta$ denotes the density of the object. However, what if $\delta$ describes a physical quality other than density -- like temperature, brightness, etc? What would the physical interpretation of this "center of $\delta$" represent for that object?

Answer (score 1):

It would be the "center of delta". Common values of delta are: pressure, buoyancy, gravity (which differs from mass), population (used in demography), and more.